# Swift JSON request to PHP web server to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, json, swift, request

I am a beginner and am working on a study project. I want to transfer the swift variables to my web server via php document. That means a Swift request to PHP.

This is my Swift code:

```
  let myUrl = URL(string: "http://example.net/stock_service3.php");

        var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!)

        request.httpMethod = "POST"// Compose a query string

        let postString = "firstName=51&lastName=6";

        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

            if error != nil
            {
                print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
                return
            }

            // You can print out response object
            print("response = \(String(describing: response))")

            //Let's convert response sent from a server side script to a NSDictionary object:
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

                if let parseJSON = json {

                    // Now we can access value of First Name by its key
                    let firstNameValue = parseJSON["firstName"] as? String
                    print("firstNameValue: \(String(describing: firstNameValue))")




                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
```

and this is the PHP and MySQL code:

```
<?php

// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect(".......".........".........");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$firstName= $_REQUEST["firstName"];
$lastName = $_REQUEST["lastName"];

// Select all of our stocks from table 'stock_tracker'
$sql ="SELECT m.*


      , ( ACOS( COS( RADIANS( $firstName) ) 
              * COS( RADIANS( m.latitude ) )
              * COS( RADIANS( m.longitude ) - RADIANS( $lastName) )
              + SIN( RADIANS($firstName ) )
              * SIN( RADIANS( m.Latitude) )
          )
        * 6371
        ) AS distance_in_km

  FROM TankBilliger m
  HAVING distance_in_km <= 100
 ORDER BY distance_in_km ASC
 LIMIT 100";

// Confirm there are results
if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql))
{
    // We have results, create an array to hold the results
        // and an array to hold the data
    $resultArray = array();
    $tempArray = array();

    // Loop through each result
    while($row = $result->fetch_object())
    {
        // Add each result into the results array
        $tempArray = $row;
        array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
    }

    // Encode the array to JSON and output the results

    echo json_encode($resultArray);
}

// Close connections
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Somehow it doesn't work and I don't know why.

Comment: "Somehow it don't work and I don't know why"  What is 'it'?  Which line?

Comment: You need to change this so if it fails to connect or run the query, it still returns valid JSON. Presently you are just echoing an error, so that will not be parseable as JSON.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.